# Javascript: Get Notified when fragment is added to the DOM

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, appendchild, notify

### **What I want**

I'm loading a fragment of HTML from server side with AJAX, and I'm appending it to the document, and I would like a way to get notified when the fragment is fully added into the dom.

I'm doing something like this:

```
// Load photos.html from the server with ajax
var instance = loadPageWithAjax('photos.html')

// Wait for response
instance.success = function(response){
   // Create Parent Object
   // Note that I MUST create a new div in my project
   var box = document.createElement('div');
       box.id = 'photos-box';

   // Insert html response to the box's innerHTML
   box.innerHTML = response;

   // Append box to the dom
   document.body.appendChild(box);
}
```

And when the fragment is added to the dom I would like to work with the contents in it, but I can't because I don't know when the fragment was actually added into the dom.

### **What I tried**

I tried to append a script after the response:

```
document.getElementById('photo-box') = response 
                                     + '<script>alert(\'loaded\')</script>';
```

It is added but doesn't loads as a script I don't really know why?

Then I tried to append it as a new Object which partly works:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.innerHTML = 'alert(\'loaded\')';
document.getElementById('photo-box').appendChild(script);
```

But it loads faster than the other parts of the fragment.

**So what is the right way to get notified when the fragment is added to the dom?**

Comment: Why not just fully set up the object before adding it to the DOM, so you don't need to do this?  Or, you could just call setTimeout and check when it is added to the DOM and just loop, perhaps waiting 100ms in between your check.

Comment: @James Black What do you mean by this `Why not just fully set up the object before adding it to the DOM`? Well I don't think that setTimeout is good because the load speed can vary, maybe a setInterval, but these solutions are really dirty :|

Comment: Why not just do your processing in the ajax success callback after appending your content to the DOM.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding but the convention in all browsers is that `innerHTML` is blocking; it won't return until everything within it has been added to the dom, so the dom is infact ready when it returns.

Comment: @AlexK. maybe you are right my example is not the actual code what I use to make it more simple to understand my problem, but I will modify my example.

Comment: I edited my question a little please check it out, @david because as I know the parent div is loaded faster then it's childNodes, and I need to work with the childNodes

Comment: dose loadPageWithAjax() contain the status and response codes?

Comment: @david in short yes, but `loadPageWithAjax()` is just a fictional function, in my project I have access to every feature of the xmlHTTP module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `innerHTML` setter as well as the `appendChild` methods are synchronous, so the DOM is updated immediately.

You probably want to be informed when all stylesheets and images are loaded. (innerHTML does not work with scripts)

This is a bit tricky. You're gonna have to iterate over all images and check their `loaded` state, then add an `onload` handler to each image that has not been loaded.
For stylesheets, it's even more complicated. See [yepnope.js](https://github.com/SlexAxton/yepnope.js/blob/master/src/yepnope.js#L105) for a possible implementation.

Comment: You are right, but I already figured out my problem in an other way.

Answer (score 0):

Im sorry don't fully understand but if the `instance.success = function(response){}` is fired once you receive the response you should be able to call a function after  `document.body.appendChild(box)`, is this correct or am i way off?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, `instance.success` is fired once the server has responded with a response, then I can work with the response as a string. When I append the box to the document body then there are parts in the box's innerHTML which are not loaded as it was appended into the dom, these are images, scripts, stylesheets etc., so I can't just call a function after the `appendChild`, especially because in my project I need to work with the images and their width and height for example are not readable until they are fully loaded.

Comment: by what your saying sounds to me is thats the response from the server contains mixed content like <script>, css tags, which if thats the case that why its not working, but say if you had those values in object like json, then it should work as expected, with a little bit more work